# Know location and IP address

Tags: ip, account-security

Today someone tried to access my LinkedIn account. When I logged into my LinkedIn account, I received PIN by mail. So how can I know the location and IP address of the hacker?

Comment: Why would you want that information? What would you do with that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Only LinkedIn administrators have that information and they only release private information of their users to law enforcement agencies after providing a proper reason and documentation proving their legitimacy.

I would like to point out that there is a good chance that someone tried to login to your account accidentally, as a server administrator it's not very common but it does happen that a legit user misspell their username and accidentally make an attempt at logging into another account, or even when trying to get recovery code when they forget their passwords. So you don't really have to worry about begin hacked. Unless you have really good reason to think someone was trying to hack your account in which case you should contact authorities, provide your reasons and then let them deal with it.

Also why does your question have Firefox and Linux tag, and what's with the content?